# Организация обмена данными между двумя ListView в Android

Tags: android, listview

Есть два `ListView` с адаптерами одинакового типа. Необходимо при нажатии на элемент одного списка удалять его из списка, в котором нажали и перемещать во второй список. В моем варианте кода постоянно получается `ConcurrentModificationException`. Ниже код, который использую. Как обойти исключение или каким иным способом можно пофиксить?

```
datasource = new IngredientsDataSource(this);
datasource.open();

final List<Ingredient> values_ing = datasource.getAllIngredients();
final List<Ingredient> values_ch = values_ing.subList(0, 0);

final ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> adapter_ing = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values_ing);
list_ing.setAdapter(adapter_ing);

final ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> adapter_ch = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values_ch);
list_ch.setAdapter(adapter_ch);

list_ing.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
        final Ingredient item = values_ing.get((int)id);
        list_ing.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            values_ing.remove(item);
            adapter_ing.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        });

        list_ch.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            values_ch.add(item); /* это строка 73 */
            adapter_ch.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        });
```

А вот Logcat появляющегося исключения:

```
03-18 15:18:08.971 1027-1027/com.kochmarevsevolod.lazycook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                                                                         at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.size(AbstractList.java:360)
                                                                         at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
                                                                         at com.kochmarevsevolod.lazycook.Search_Page$1$2.run(Search_Page.java:73)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: вы адаптер обновляете в другом треде. Либо сразу делайте это в основном, либо используйте MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема со способом создания `values_ch`. Строка:

```
final List<Ingredient> values_ch = values_ing.subList(0, 0);
```

создает "окно" в начало списка `values_ing`, нулевой длины, и операции над "окном" (добавление и удаление элемента) меняют основной список тоже. При этом поведение "окна" при изменении основного списка не определено, и контракт [`AbstractList.subList`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) утверждает, что при изменении основного списка напрямую (`values_ing.remove(item);`), все действия с "окном" будут выбрасывать `ConcurrentModificationException`, что и происходит.

Просто создайте список естественным путем, через `new ArrayList()`.

Comment: zRrr - вы теперь мой кумир ))
Спасибо огромное )